# Android Studio: Explicit intent doesn't work when I want user to click on Login button and go to Login screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to learn navigation in Android Studio I used explicit intent to navigate from Main Activity page to Login screen. I have mapped this to the Login button on the Main Activity screen. What happens now is, if I click on the Login button, the app exits, instead of going to the login screen.

The .kt code for Main activity and Login activity is given below:

## .kt for Main Activity**your text**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.LoginButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        }
    }
```

## **.kt for Login Activity**

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui.login

import android.app.Activity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding

import com.example.myapplication.R

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)


        val username = binding.username
        val password = binding.password
        val login = binding.login
        val loading = binding.loading

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, LoginViewModelFactory())[LoginViewModel::class.java]

        loginViewModel.loginFormState.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
            val loginState = it ?: return@Observer

            // disable login button unless both username / password is valid
            login.isEnabled = loginState.isDataValid

            if (loginState.usernameError != null) {
                username.error = getString(loginState.usernameError)
            }
            if (loginState.passwordError != null) {
                password.error = getString(loginState.passwordError)
            }
        })

        loginViewModel.loginResult.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
            val loginResult = it ?: return@Observer

            if (loading != null) {
                loading.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            if (loginResult.error != null) {
                showLoginFailed(loginResult.error)
            }
            if (loginResult.success != null) {
                updateUiWithUser(loginResult.success)
            }
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)

            //Complete and destroy login activity once successful
            finish()
        })

        username.afterTextChanged {
            loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
                username.text.toString(),
                password.text.toString()
            )
        }

        password.apply {
            afterTextChanged {
                loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
                    username.text.toString(),
                    password.text.toString()
                )
            }

            setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
                when (actionId) {
                    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ->
                        loginViewModel.login(
                            username.text.toString(),
                            password.text.toString()
                        )
                }
                false
            }

            login.setOnClickListener {
                if (loading != null) {
                    loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                loginViewModel.login(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateUiWithUser(model: LoggedInUserView) {
        val welcome = getString(R.string.welcome)
        val displayName = model.displayName
        // TODO : initiate successful logged in experience
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "$welcome $displayName",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }

    private fun showLoginFailed(@StringRes errorString: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

/**
 * Extension function to simplify setting an afterTextChanged action to EditText components.
 */
fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
}
```

EDIT: attached crash logs from terminal:

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28651
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:30)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
05-01 18:43:08.793 28651 28651 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 12 more
```

Crash logs from Logcat are here:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iQY13YwheNgJaJocU-nlDxLWl0RyBivF/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=112440543681938917930&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Have you register LoginActivity in AndroidMenifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes I have, please find code below:
<activity
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />

Comment: Any crash? Please check Logcat and post crash report

Comment: Crash logs from terminal ad logcat are mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i've got it!

In class LoginActivity you need to initialize the binding as in MainActivity

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val username = binding.username
        val password = binding.password

        //...
    }

}
```

Let me know if helped

Comment: @Álvaro Radajczyk what is difference than my answer?

Comment: Srry, i made entire android studio project to check what was happening and when i was writing what worked to me, you replied before. I can provide entire project if needed, please, contact me

Answer (score 0):

According to log **lateinit property binding has not been initialized**

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
```

You need to initialize it before setContentView() method

```
binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: I realise the mistake now, thank you so much for your timely response!!